# Share a folder between computers in different domains

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a following problem with computers running on Windows 7. Computer A is in a domain, another computer B is a virtual machine, which is not in the domain. Without having any administrative privileges to the domain, I want to be able to share a folder between A and B, so that only I can have access to it from both computers. How can I do something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By `having any administrative privileges to the domain` I assume you mean to modify the domain, and that you are still able to have both machines (virtual or not) access it?

If this is the case just put them on the same domain, share the folders normally (over [NetBIOS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/share-files-with-someone#1TC=windows-7)) but changing the [security settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456988.aspx) to only allow access via a passworded account.

Obviously you'd need to disable the "secret" default [drive sharing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/68cfa17a-1114-40f7-9526-6415e6a512fc/disable-all-drives-dollar-share-but-enable-admin-share-admin?forum=winserverDS) and remove `everyone` from even appearing in the security list.

If you're worried about people [discovering](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7) the machine on the network I'm not sure if it's possible to stop broadcasting (and I'd be interested in finding out if someone knows).

Comment: By 'not having any administrative privileges to the domain' I meant that I am not an administrator of the domain (it is a corporate domain). I suppose I could use something like Dropbox, however I was hoping that there is a way to do that with some out-of-the-box feature. Also, I wanted to have execute privilege to that shared folder

Comment: P.S. I am not sure what you mean: "you are still able to have both machines (virtual or not) access it"? I can access the domain, but I can't add computer B to the domain and I can't add any users from the domain to the Administrative group